# Elasticsearch Incorrect http method for uri for POST

Tags: http, elasticsearch, post, get, postman

I'm attempting to POST a document to an elasticsearch cluster I have cloud hosted via elastic cloud. I have an application currently running from TheThingsNetwork that is POSTing data just fine, however when I attempt to use postman or python requests module, I receive a 405 error when POSTing. GET requests work just fine and return a status of 200.

Here's my failed POST via postman:

[image: Failed POST 405]

Here's my successful GET via postman:

[image: Successful GET - 200]

This should be something very straightforward, so I imagine I'm missing simple. Any and all help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This is because you're trying to POST to an index. Add a document type to the end of your url ex. /my_index/my_doc and you should be able to POST your document as my_doc document type.

Answer (score 9):

to anyone come to this answer looking for a solution, the `Elastic search` has been changed now index type is not supported since `ES6`and above what you need to do is

`POST -> https://youripOrDomain:9200/your_index_name/_doc/your_id`

if you leave `your_id` blank it will create one for you so it is optional

Answer (score 1):

The answers by @atorres757 and @atorres757 are correct.

One day, I tried to try the free trial provided by Elasticsearch's official website. And when I was supposed to create the index with below query.

```
POST /users
{ "first_name": "Rishikesh", "last_name": "Agrawani", "age": 29}
```

I got below result on Kibana DevTools console.

```
{
    "error" : "Incorrect HTTP method for uri [/users?pretty=true] and method [POST], allowed: [GET, DELETE, PUT, HEAD]",
    "status" : 405
}
```

Finally, I tried the below query by just appending `/_doc` to the previous endpoint.

```
POST /users/_doc
{ "first_name": "Rishikesh", "last_name": "Agrawani", "age": 29}
```

which gives below result (successful).

```
{
  "_index" : "users",
  "_type" : "_doc",
  "_id" : "tHTmZn0BRhCCQAKysEr1",
  "_version" : 1,
  "result" : "created",
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 2,
    "successful" : 2,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "_seq_no" : 1,
  "_primary_term" : 1
}
```

Finally, we can validate the insertion with below query.

```
GET /users/_doc/tHTmZn0BRhCCQAKysEr1
```

which gives the below result.

```
{
  "_index" : "users",
  "_type" : "_doc",
  "_id" : "tHTmZn0BRhCCQAKysEr1",
  "_version" : 1,
  "_seq_no" : 1,
  "_primary_term" : 1,
  "found" : true,
  "_source" : {
    "first_name" : "Rishikesh",
    "last_name" : "Agrawani",
    "age" : 29
  }
}
```

Thanks. I haven't tried any special but just added working examples by using the available answers to make the solutions more clearer.